# Thus was the final act of ferocious farce

Tags: vocabulary, writing, reading

I'm having a hard time understanding this sentence. I don't get the function of the verb LEFT in it.

"**Thus was the final act of ferocious farce left unti**l that bloody week in May 1871 when some thirty thousand Communards died."

Does it mean:

So, the final act of that ferocious farse was left to the bloody week in May 1871 when...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not positive without more context, but this is what I'm pretty sure it means.

> Left: past and past participle of leave. [Source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/left)

So the sentence could mean one of two things.

1) They have a final act of ferocious farce, but they decided to "leave" (delay) it until later, more specifically, until that bloody week in May.

or

2) Thus is referring to another past "Act of ferocious farce" and they are saying that was the last one "left" (remaining), until they had another act of ferocious farce in that bloody week of May.